# Exposing wsdl through WSO2

Tags: wsdl, wso2

How can I expose the wsdl through WSO2 governance registry. I have promoted the service lifecylce through to production and was hoping to get an URL some which I can share with the service consumers for discovering the service and the contract. Any pointers are appreciated.

Update: "URL some " is a typo..  apologies. In a nutshell I am unable to comprehend how to accomplish UDDI / WS-Discovery aspects with instructions in the document. I am simply looking to expose the wsdl through a url such as this "host:port/services/environment/myservice?wsdl" and would like to have the flexibility of managing service endpoints for each environment. I have a client which has to discover the wsdl's dynamically and i am figuring out ways to expose it to them. In the process, stumbled upon the wso2 product and trying to figure out.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "an URL some"...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ws-discovery](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance453/Support+for+WS-Discovery)

another option is , you can use [UDDI](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance453/The+usage+of+UDDI+APIs) registry to find your services..